# WPBakery Page Builder - How to create post programmatically

Tags: php, json, wordpress, base64, wpbakery

I have purchased a theme that came with WPBakery Page Builder,

I have about a 100 posts styled the same way,

I plan to import roughly 6,000 more, but this time, programmatically.

With WPBakery, I can export a sample page, it then results in this code:

```
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
```

Which is obviously base64 encoded from:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"uid";s:9:"c7be0dd27";s:4:"attr";a:18:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:8:"bg_color";s:0:"";s:8:"bg_image";s:0:"";s:11:"bg_position";s:20:"no-repeat;left top;;";s:7:"bg_size";s:4:"auto";s:12:"bg_video_mp4";s:0:"";s:12:"bg_video_ogv";s:0:"";s:11:"padding_top";s:1:"0";s:14:"padding_bottom";s:1:"0";s:7:"divider";s:0:"";s:9:"decor_top";s:0:"";s:12:"decor_bottom";s:0:"";s:10:"navigation";s:0:"";s:5:"style";s:0:"";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:10:"section_id";s:0:"";s:10:"visibility";s:0:"";s:4:"hide";s:0:"";}s:5:"wraps";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:3:"uid";s:9:"e4b94c5ba";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/1";s:5:"items";a:5:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:9:"map_basic";s:3:"uid";s:9:"d5dd0f504";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/1";s:6:"fields";a:4:{s:6:"iframe";s:0:"";s:7:"address";s:50:"205 catherine street, ottawa ";s:4:"zoom";s:2:"13";s:6:"height";s:3:"300";}}i:1;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:13:"fancy_heading";s:3:"uid";s:9:"80a785149";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/3";s:6:"fields";a:8:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:2:"h1";s:1:"0";s:7:"content";s:52:"<h2><a href="tel:613-228-6700">613-228-6700</a></h2>";s:5:"style";s:4:"icon";s:4:"icon";s:9:"icon-call";s:6:"slogan";s:0:"";s:7:"animate";s:0:"";s:7:"classes";s:0:"";}}i:2;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:13:"fancy_heading";s:3:"uid";s:9:"c08ff4596";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/3";s:6:"fields";a:8:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:2:"h1";s:1:"0";s:7:"content";s:87:"<h2><a href="mailto:contact@luclaverdure.com">contact@luclaverdure.com</a></h2>";s:5:"style";s:4:"icon";s:4:"icon";s:10:"icon-email";s:6:"slogan";s:0:"";s:7:"animate";s:0:"";s:7:"classes";s:0:"";}}i:3;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:13:"fancy_heading";s:3:"uid";s:9:"jonmbii3x";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/3";s:6:"fields";a:8:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:2:"h1";s:1:"0";s:7:"content";s:83:"<h2><a href="http://luclaverdure.com" target="_blank">luclaverdure.com</a></h2>";s:5:"style";s:4:"icon";s:4:"icon";s:9:"icon-link";s:6:"slogan";s:0:"";s:7:"animate";s:0:"";s:7:"classes";s:0:"";}}i:4;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:10:"blockquote";s:3:"uid";s:9:"84e0f221a";s:4:"size";s:3:"1/1";s:6:"fields";a:5:{s:7:"content";s:377:"Blablabla1234 ";s:6:"author";s:0:"";s:4:"link";s:0:"";s:6:"target";s:1:"0";s:7:"classes";s:0:"";}}}s:4:"attr";a:9:{s:8:"bg_color";s:0:"";s:8:"bg_image";s:0:"";s:11:"bg_position";s:20:"no-repeat;left top;;";s:7:"bg_size";s:4:"auto";s:7:"move_up";s:0:"";s:7:"padding";s:0:"";s:13:"column_margin";s:0:"";s:14:"vertical_align";s:3:"top";s:5:"class";s:0:"";}}}}}
```

How can I import this json configuration programmatically into wordpress...

Pseudocode:

```
foreach(postToImport) {
    // @wp_insert_post funk?
    TheMagicImportFunctionINeed(base64(json));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is to use the custom field:

### mfn-page-items

Hence code would be similar to:

```
    // insert the post and set the category
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
        'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
        'post_title' => $your_title,
        'post_content' => $your_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',   // if you prefer
        'ping_status' => 'closed',      // if you prefer
    ));

    if ($post_id) {
        // insert post meta
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'mfn-page-items', "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");
    }
```

Cheers!